# CUDA with cmake. Config file not found

Tags: c++, cuda, cmake, ros, catkin

I am trying to have CUDA working with catkin (ros) which is essentially cmake. I do not have a .cu files yet. As a first step I am wanting to add `CUDA` in `find_package`

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  roscpp
  message_generation
  CUDA
)
```

After this the cmake systems gives out the following error :

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package CUDA.

  Set CUDA_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for
  CUDA.  The file will have one of the following names:

    CUDAConfig.cmake
    cuda-config.cmake
```

I can confirm that CUDA on my system works fine. I can successfully run the cuda samples : bandwidthTest and deviceQuery. I have cuda-5.5 in `/usr/local/cuda-5.5/`.

```
[eeuser@roadrunner bin]$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2013 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jul_17_18:36:13_PDT_2013
Cuda compilation tools, release 5.5, V5.5.0
```

I can also confirm that with cmake I have the FindCUDA installed.

```
[eeuser@roadrunner bin]$ locate FindCUDA
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindCUDA
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindCUDA/make2cmake.cmake
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindCUDA/parse_cubin.cmake
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindCUDA/run_nvcc.cmake
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a wrong usage

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  roscpp
  message_generation
  CUDA
)
```

Instead use it as -

```
FIND_PACKAGE(CUDA REQUIRED)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  roscpp
  message_generation
)
```